# Proxy for selenium rc driver in java

Tags: java, proxy, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

How can i do proxy configuration for selenium in Java?

I am connecting to selenium with:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar lib/selenium-server.jar");
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*safari", "www.example.com");
```

I want to configure free proxy without username and password credentials for the same which would be running the selenium application in the safari browser.

I have tried the code below to set proxy for the tests

`System.setProperty("http:proxyHost","207.229.122.162");
System.setProperty("http:proxyPort","3128");`

but the above code is not working fine !! its even accepting null as arguments ,

Please suggest me some way to resolve the issue !!

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set Proxy Configuration in java code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622547/how-to-set-proxy-configuration-in-java-code)

Comment: Hi! I think you can find the answer to your question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622547/how-to-set-proxy-configuration-in-java-code - in short, use System.setProperty to set the proxy configuration.

Comment: Hey!! i have tried the System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","112.81.25.52");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort","3128"); 

but still it doesn't work !! it is even accepting when i pass some random numbers or even null values ...

Comment: @Zarkonnen : is there any other way to config proxy in selenium ide other than System.setProperty() , and also working for safari browser in  MAC os

Comment: @Aspirant could you share more java code and how do you read this property?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize run configuration under netbeans. Project Properties -> Run. Regards.

Comment: Hey i could not get your point of customizing Run configuration in Netbeans !! could you please be more specific regarding the same !!

Answer (score 0):

You could add the desired ip to the proxy bypass field in global network settings.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to define properties from console(using maven) then read it in java:

Define property:

```
mvn clean verify -Dserver_ip="127.0.0.1" -Dport="4444"
```

Read in java:

```
System.getProperty("server_ip");
```

It's more flexible than hardcoded values in code